# Wordpress Image Watermark Plugins didn't working

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I install a plugin called `Image Watermark` in my WordPress site, it doesn't work at all, I tried to bulk the image library, it says `successfully` but the watermark didn't show up at all.

So I want to try to find where the problem is, but how to do this? If I just use the `wp_debug` it'll show too many errors (it's an old website from 2004).

I already tried to google **how to fix Image Watermark WordPress plugin**, etc. but I can't found the answer, right now I'm using the latest version of WordPress `4.9.5` and the latest Image Watermark version `1.6.4`.

And I already tried to search other plugins for watermarking, but some already gone, and some already not compatible, and the most recommended is this plugin. The `Image Watermark` but it doesn't work at all, Please help.

Sorry for this silly question just learned Wordpress codes 2 weeks ago.

Comment: You might have more success posting on the support page for this plugin on wordpress.org. Questions about plugins (unless you're writing one) are kind of off topic here.

Comment: I already post it but no answer, so that's why I try look for a help in SO @Myles

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have done the correct configuration of the plugin. 
Configuration like this - https://ibb.co/f52XU7

Comment: Yeah I already do that, it's not from the settings I think, because there are a lot of people had this problem too with their WordPress website

Comment: Any error or warning you are getting when you upload the image?

Comment: No I don't, that's why I confused why does it happened,it says successfully, but nothing happened

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-turn-off-php-errors-in-wordpress/  This have alternate ways to enable the WordPress errors ON

Comment: well I already tried that one, I need something that shows only the plugins error, I don't know it's possible or not

Comment: Because I already try to show the errors, and try to `apply watermark`, it doesn't returns any error, but no watermark as well

Comment: Can you install the plugin on the fresh WP and try there if it is works, you must check you website code i hope this can help you figure out the error is in website or plugin. .

Comment: I already did that too, I've a fresh WP in my local and cloud, both of them were working

Comment: I even already tried disable all plugins except the watermark, but it still doesn't do anything, I don't know why it's happening tho

Comment: OK I'll try using it, hope it's not breaking the site